# Pass the "name" of a variable in r

Tags: r, variables, pass-by-reference

I was wondering if there is a way to pass the "name" of a variable in R.
What I want is to make the following function more generic:

```
a <- "old"
test <- function () {
   assign("a", "new", envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
test()
a
```

What I don't want is a function that only works if the variable I want to change is called "a", so I was wondering if I can do something like passing the variable name as an argument and then call the assign function with that name. Something like this:

```
a <- "old"
test <- function (varName) {
   assign(varName, "new", envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

test(a) #!!!!! Here !!!!!
a
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean this - `test(varName = 'a')` ?

Comment: You want to reassign the value of `a` from `old` to `new` or you want to assign the value of `new` to a new variable `old` (if its the latter, your function does that, the former is what `<-` is for...)? Also, if you find yourself using `assign` you're almost always doing it wrong.

Comment: Actually what I really want to do is pass to a function a variable from a environment without assigning the environment to the function itself. Something like myFunction(e1$myVar) where the function myfunction(theVar) does an assignment to "theVar" and it modifies myVar. But I can't get it to work.

Comment: I still don't understand at all what you're hoping for.  Please edit you question to include desired inputs and outputs as well as a description of the larger problem you're looking to solve.  I have a feeling that there is a much better option than dealing with `assign` and passing environments around...

Comment: @Justin I think he's looking for a modification of `assign` that takes a variable, not a character. Put another way, I think he's looking for a variation of `<-` that takes an environment argument.

Comment: Ok sorry for the mess, I'll edit the question soon, I can't quite do it now.

Comment: @BrunoFollon While I think I understand *what* you want to do, I'm still clueless as to the *why*. When you edit, please include (a) why `<-` with a variable in the global environment and (b) why `assign` with a character don't work.

Comment: You should check variable with name "old" (print(old)) after executing your code!!!

Comment: @shujaa there you go, I changed the question. I know it's very different but I thought a lot and I think now it explains better my problem. By the way, you got it right now that I notice, I'm looking for a `<-` variation that takes an environment argument.

Comment: @BrunoFollon I think I may have hurt your question with my comments. Wojciech answered what I thought you were asking, but it looks like I was wrong. If this is still an issue you'd like addressed, I'd recommend editing this question to match my earlier comments and accepting Wojciech's answer, then asking a new question about your `insertDoubleListEvent`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to pass variable name (as character) you can use following trick:

```
test <- function (varName) {
  assign(deparse(substitute(varName)), "new", envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the string `'a'` to your function will work.

```
a <- "old"
test <- function (varName) {
   assign(varName, "new", envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
test('a')
a
# [1] "new"
```

However, as I said in my comments, I don't think this is the correct solution to your problem.  If you want to ask a more general question about the thing you're trying to do, I bet there is a more "R-ish" solution.